# Type 'WebResource' is not defined. while "Publish" a website or web application in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, web-applications, publish

I had a problem some days ago, and I found a solution for it. Now I decided to share my solution with stackoverflow too.

Problem:

I had a web application in visual studio, and some times when I tried to do the publish process in Visual Studio, I got an error saying that:

> Type 'WebResource' is not defined

I want to find a solution for this issue and resolve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing many investigations, I found the solution. To resolve this issue, all you need to do is to include your class name with full-part naming.

Imagine that our class name is `WebResource` and we are getting an error that says

> Type 'WebResource' is not defined

So to solve it, instead of saying `WebResource` we need to say `System.Web.UI.WebResource`.

This is a simple solution for this nerve-racking issue.